# where I can use the word "often"?

Tags: word-usage

Hello all I have question for you , where I can use the word "often" in spanish mean "a menudo" in spanish a example is so :

"a menudo puedo hablar ingles contigo" in english is so : "I often can speak english with you " is correct my vocabulary I use the word "often" or where I can use that word in my normal life?

Comment: There's no need to apologise for "bad English". We accept that you're not a native speaker. Provided you have made an attempt to be understood will will forgive your errors.

Comment: ok I see my question is for improve my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer when you can use it, *often* is used to show that something happens frequently. For example:

```
I often go on a walk in the mornings.
```

*Often* here shows that it happens regularly.

In your example, I would guess it translates better to `I can *usually* speak English with you`, which implies that sometimes you try and end up not being able to, maybe because you don't know the right words or something similar. Correct me if the I got that wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My Spanish is *bada* too but perhaps a better phrasing of

> I often can speak english with you

is

> I can usually talk to you in English.

Comment: oh I can see is similar? it means the same
?

Comment: It is more grammatical and idiomatic. At the basic level, *"I often can . . ."* should be *"I can often . . ."*